# How to configure a Reactive Resource Server to use a JWT with a symmetric key?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

On the Authorization server, my Jwt was generated with this:

```
      @Value("${jwt.key}")
      private String jwtKey;

      @Override
      public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
      }
    
      @Bean
      public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
      }
    
      @Bean
      public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        var converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(jwtKey);
        return converter;
      }
```

Now on the Reactive Resource server side:

```
  @Value("${jwt.key}")
  private String jwtKey;

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt(jwtSpec -> {...})
        .and.build();
  }
```

How can I configure my Reactive Resource Server to use that token, given the signing key ?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? (And if not, why not since you're using Webflux?)

Comment: Yes, I am using spring boot

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about. a jwt has no "key". And you don't use a "token". You sign a jwt using a jwk (json web key) and you have private key in your authorization server, and you distribute a public key to all applications that need to verify the signage. You standard, provide a url for the resource server so that the authorization server so that it can rotate the keys at given intervals. And you should not "share" the same key between two servers. You need a keypair.

Comment: if you get your terminology correct and understand how you do it, it is documented here in the spring boot security reference manual. I suggest you read up on how oauth and jwts work, the documentation is really really good https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-public-key

Comment: You can sign a Jwt with asymmetric key (the case you just described) and with a symmetric key, that is not public or private key, just a single signing key. I took the second option for now. I know how to work with asymmetric key: `jwt(jwtSpec -> { jwtSpec.jwkSetUri(jwkEndpoint);})`, you just specify the the jwkEndPoint as you said. I don't see in the doc how to proceed for a symmetric key case.

Comment: Then why are you not using the built-in Boot configuration for resource servers?

Comment: Please let me know that config... that is why I am here. I know how to manage for non-reactive. But for reactive, it seems like it has to go through `.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt(jwtSpec -> {...})` . I just don't know man

Comment: why i dont talk about symmetric keys is because from a security perspective it is bad practice. You should never have shared keys, because if you have many services they all would need the same shared key, so symmetric key should be avoided and never used imho.

Comment: You are all right, I totally agree, the symmetric is faster for proof of concept I think. I will switch to asymmetric keys when I will have more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  @Value("${jwt.key}")
  private String jwtKey;

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt(jwtSpec -> { jwtSpec.decoder(jwtDecoder()); })
        .and.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(jwtKey, "HMACSHA256");
    return NimbusJwtDecoder
            .withSecretKey(secretKey)
            .macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256)
            .build();
 }
```

Unless you specify sign algorithm, authorization server uses HMACSHA256 as default algorithm. So you need to specify this in resource server config.

Comment: Just a small correction, it worked with `ReactiveJwtDecoder`, and `NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder`

Comment: Should be:    `SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(jwtKey.getbytes(), "HMACSHA256");`